# Asp button can't find eventhandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, events, web

I'm having issues using ASP to register an event on a button. It gives me the error:

```
CS1061: 'ASP.permissions_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'CreateEndUserClick' and no extension method 'CreateEndUserClick' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.permissions_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When I visit the page in a browser, it still compiles successfully. Basically it can't find the onclick handler, however I can't figure out why.

This is my asp file Permissions.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainLayout.master" AutoEventWireup="True"  CodeBehind="Permissions.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebProj._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Button ID="Button_CreateEndUser" runat="server" OnClick="CreateEndUserClick" Text="Create New End User/Group" />
</asp:Content>
```

I removed some of the non relevant elements of the page obviously.

And my codebehind file Permissions.aspx.cs:

```
namespace WebProj
{
    public partial class Permissions : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button_CreateEndUser;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void CreateEndUserClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button_CreateEndUser.Text = "Hamstertext";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it's unable to find the function. Could it possibly be because I use content tags to place it inside a master file?

I'd greatly appreciate any help or points in the right direction on how to approach this problem.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Page` directive try correcting the `Inherits` attribute:

```
Inherits="WebProj.Permissions"
```

This attribute should contain name of code behind class, which in your case is `WebProj.Permissions` (not `WebProj._Default`). Note that the class specified here should be defined in the file specified in the `CodeBehind` attribute (`Permissions.aspx.cs` in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
    Inherits="WebProj.Permissions"
```

Reason, you have the **namespace WebProj** and the **class Permissions**. So inherit must use the same.